# Reading in Data (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having trouble loading data into my Java program. The program says the file exists, but FileReader is giving a FileNotFoundException. I have tried the full path and made sure all files are closed. I am using the Eclipse IDE. Any suggestions?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;

public class ReadCSV {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filepath = "/Users/mrodgers/Documents/other/languages/java/eclipse/ReadCSV/src/data.csv";
        //String filepath = "~/Desktop/data.csv";
        //String filepath = "data.csv";

        File mjr = new File(filepath);
        System.out.println(mjr.exists());

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(mjr);
//      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have right to read that file? @mjr2000

Comment: Print out the values of `mjr.canRead()` to check that you have permission to read the file, and `mjr.isFile()` to check that it is a plain file and not a directory or something else.

Comment: They both print true.

Comment: What is the exact text of the FileNotFoundException ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

Comment: Yeah, see my answer. When you tell people you have a FileNotFound exception, they do not realize that you mean it's a compile error, they think it's a runtime error. You have a compile error. You must put a try/catch around that constructor, which has FileNotFoundException as a checked exception.

Answer (score 0):

This works on my machine, with the filename set to one that I have of course.

But I *did* have to wrap the creation of FileReader in a try/catch for FileNotFound exception -- is that what you mean? The compiler tells you that you must catch FileNotFound if you use that FileReader constructor?

Unless/until you do that, eclipse should (and does, on my machine) mark the call to the FileReader constructor as an error because that exception is not caught.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

  public class FilePlay
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          String filepath = "/Users/ralph/Documents/My Chess Database/r-b.pgn";
          //String filepath = "~/Desktop/data.csv";
          //String filepath = "data.csv";

          File mjr = new File(filepath);
          System.out.println(mjr.exists());

          try 
          {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(mjr);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
          }
          catch (FileNotFoundException fnf)
          {
            fnf.printStackTrace();
          }

      }
  }
```

Comment: Why do I need a try/catch to load a file? I am trying to load the data. The try/catch does not load the data.

Comment: A checked exception is one which, if in a "throws" clause in a method definition, must be checked by a method calling it. Many exceptions are "unchecked", meaning that they are thrown but are not required to be checked by callers. I think the idea behind checked exceptions was to ensure that callers considered standard error conditions and handled them, rather than just testing a "happy path" and not considering them. There is a fashion now for using only unchecked.

Comment: Well, no one can help you if you don't give enough information. *Copy* the error message, instead of telling us its name; if it's a stacktrace, we need to see the entire thing, with line numbers. You also need to tell us what the first line number in your code corresponds to. Trim your problem down to the minimum that demonstrates the problem, you often learn what the problem is yourself doing that alone. We're willing to help, but we aren't mind readers, and in fact most people here are reluctant to guess at information that isn't provided.